# Dequeue classic-themes.min.css

Tags: css, block-editor, globals

since version 6.1, wordpress loads classic-themes.min.css on our websites and crashes all of my buttons styles.

I only want to see my own styles in the frontend, so i'm dequeueing WP Styles like this:

```
function disable_gutenberg_wp_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_style('wp-block-library');
    wp_dequeue_style('wp-block-library-theme');
}
add_filter('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'disable_gutenberg_wp_enqueue_scripts', 100);

function prefix_remove_core_block_styles() {
    global $wp_styles;

    foreach ( $wp_styles->queue as $key => $handle ) {
        if ( strpos( $handle, 'wp-block-' ) === 0 ) {
            wp_dequeue_style( $handle );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'prefix_remove_core_block_styles' );

function prefix_remove_global_styles() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'global-styles' );
} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'prefix_remove_global_styles', 100 );

remove_filter( 'render_block', 'wp_render_layout_support_flag', 10, 2 );
remove_filter( 'render_block', 'wp_render_elements_support', 10, 2 );
remove_filter( 'render_block', 'gutenberg_render_elements_support', 10, 2 );
```

Do i miss something thats loading the classic-themes.min.css?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The script loader calls the classic themes CSS, see [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/6.1/src/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L3667).

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to @t31os

I achieved dequeuing the stylesheet with this code:

```
function disable_classic_theme_styles() {
    wp_deregister_style('classic-theme-styles');
    wp_dequeue_style('classic-theme-styles');
}
add_filter('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'disable_classic_theme_styles', 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

I am removing it with the following code in my functions.php

```
remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_enqueue_classic_theme_styles' );
```

Comment: This worked for me in WP 6.1.1.